# Conditions For Unbiased Linear Combination of Estimators

Tags: self-study, unbiased-estimator

### Notation:

- $\mu$: true population parameter to be estimated
- $T_i$: mutually independent unbiased estimators of $\mu$
- $Var(T_i)$ = $\sigma_i$
- $T = a + \sum_i^n b_iT_i$
- $a$, $b_i$ $\in \mathbb{R}$

### Question:

Conditions on $a$ & $b_i$ for T to be an unbiased estimator of $\mu$

### Attempt:

Say T is an unbiased estimator of $mu$ 
$$\implies E[a + \sum_i^n b_iT_i] = \mu$$
$$\implies a + \sum_i^n b_iE[T_i] = \mu$$
$$\implies \mu(\sum_i^n b_i) = \mu-a$$
$$\implies (\sum_i^n b_i) = 1-\frac{a}{\mu}$$
Now, $\mu$ is unknown true population parameter, hence the value of constants cannot depend on $\mu$ 
Thus, this forces 
$a=0$
& $\sum_1^nb_i=1$

Comment: Your conclusion is correct.  But from the penultimate step to the last step, it may be slightly better to make the conclusion based on $\left(1 - \sum b_i\right)\mu = a$ (or just drop the last step).